# What to do if repairing one disk made the other unrecognized?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk-utility, partition, repair

Originally I had two drives, an HDD and an SSD (my boot drive). The HDD had a 100gb partition on it that used to have windows installed on it, but that partition got locked and became unusable. When I tried to remove the partition I couldn't.

So I restarted into single user mode on that HDD (it also had OSX installed even though it wasn't my boot drive) and repaired the disk using fsck -fy. I then rebooted and couldn't see my SSD, so now I'm on my HDD, and my SSD seems to be nowhere to be found. It's not recognized in disk utility or anything.

Edit with more information: the SSD is running mavericks, and the HDD has 10.8 on it which I think is mountain lion.

Also, in terminal ls /Volumes/ doesn't show the SSD.

After restarting my computer, the disk now shows up in disk utility, but nothing else.

[image: What it looks like in disk utility]

When I run the diskutil list command in terminal, I got this:

```
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            749.3 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
```

What does EFI mean? is that why it's not working properly? I'm also worried that because I have ReFit on my machine it's messing the indexing up or something.

Comment: Some more information: the SSD is running mavericks, and the HDD has 10.8 on it which I think is mountain lion.

Comment: The [EFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface) partition is perfectly normal. As you disk now appears in Disk Utility, can you verify it from there? Or from a [recovery boot](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718)?

Comment: @Édouard After I restarted the disk actually disappeared from disk utility. I haven't tried a recovery boot yet but I'll get back to you when I do.

Comment: But the drive appears when you run, say, `df`?

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: I went and got it checked out and I think it is a hardware issue.